# Convert HTML menu in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to output this HTML menu in WordPress. I am confused how to give classes to ul and the first a tag under ul. Thanks.

```
<div class="side-menu">
<ul>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Holi Tourism <span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-more">
        <li><a href="#">Mount Kailash Yatra</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Char Dham Yatra</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Muktinath Yatra</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lumbini Yatra</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Destination <span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-more">
        <li><a href="#">Nepal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Thailand</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Singapore</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">America</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">India</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix"><a href="#">Visa Assistance<em class="fa fa-plus"></em></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to change the second and third ul class only not all of them. And hw to I give classes and other details to the a tag in between li and ul tags.

Comment: This is a bootstrap menu, look for a bootstrap menu nav_walker. Google it.

Comment: Thank you. :) How do it I miss such an obvious thing.

Answer (score 5):

Steps:
1. Create a menu from admin of your wordpress and
then, call it in your **header.php** file in the theme like,

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu'   => 'Left Navigation Menu', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav')); ?>
```

`"Left Navigation Menu"` is the name of your menu.

Comment: but how do i give specific classes to the "ul" tag and other details like class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" to the "a" tag and also give classes to the "span" tag. Thanks

Comment: @Suhan Use `walker` class to extend the functionality.

Comment: <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'menu',
            'theme_location'    => 'menu',
            'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" role="menu" >%3$s</ul>',
            'depth'             => 0,
            'container'         => '',
            'menu_class'        => 'dropdown-menu',
   
        );
    ?>

Comment: and how do i give classes to the "a" tag and add the span tag with classes in wordpress?

Comment: When you add menu item in admin then there is a option "Screen Option". Add check the class optin and then you will add class on menu item a tag.

Comment: @Haninder Singh Thanks. Can you also tell me how do I add the span tag with classes?

Comment: and what about other details of a tag like --> data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"

Comment: Suhan if my answer is userful then please like my answer

Comment: I am not able to upvote but I will accept it if I can get the complete solution. Thanks.